# Simple event correlation using Elasticsearch and Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm doing some optimization work on some database stuff and the system writes down log files. Basically I want to optimize some stuff then restore the original customer db-dump and re-run the whole thing. My log files look something like that:

```
2016-05-10 15:43:18,135 DEBUG [WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:64181]] d.h.h.h.c.d.m... [1517]: doing thing #2081087 took 26831ms
2016-05-10 15:05:18,135 DEBUG [WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:64181]] d.h.h.h.c.d.m... [1517]: doing thing #20887 took 4051ms
2016-05-10 15:02:18,135 DEBUG [WorkerThread#0[127.0.0.1:64181]] d.h.h.h.c.d.m... [1517]: doing thing #1087 took 261ms
```

I want to correlate these events over the different runs now to have some statistical data which change did what. So, what I want is a result like

```
             |   run 1   |   run 2   |   run 3   | ... |
thing #20887 |   261ms   |   900ms   |   100ms   | ... |
thing #1087  |   4051ms  |   9000ms  |   2000ms  | ... |
```

How can I correlate these events using Elasticsearch and visualize it with Kibana?

Comment: How come the timestamps are in descending order in your log file?

Comment: oh, I created those lines by hand, so there is no reason for that

Comment: Ok, is there a way that you could add some indication in the log about the current run? like `... doing thing #2081087 in run 2 took 26831ms`

Comment: that is no problem actually